# Javascript RegExp with tagged expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to know if there is a way to perform replacement with regular expressions in JS using tagged expressions, like scintilla engine does (used in Notepad++, for example).
For instance, to replace numbers with a colon as decimal separator by a dot, you may use the following expressions in Notepad++:

regexp: `/([0-9]+),([0-9]{2})/`
replace: `\1.\2`

Could I do something like this in JS?

Regards
José

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
str = str.replace(/([0-9]+),([0-9]{2})/, '$1.$2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You sure can!

```
"My test string with a 56,35% chance of success".replace(/([0-9]+),([0-9]{2})/gi, "$1.$2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace`.  Good documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace